# Assign value to data based on value order of different column by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to assign a value to duplicate values based off the order of another column between a date range.  The duplicate values are in the name column.  I was thinking of putting together a case statement, but do not think it will produce what I am looking for, which is as follows:

From:

```
Name  Action    Date  
0001  Update    2017-01-02
0001  Update-A  2017-02-09
0001  Update-A  2017-03-02
0001  Update-A  2017-01-05
0002  Update-A  2017-02-18
0002  Update-A  2017-03-17
0003  Update-A  2017-02-09
0003  Update    2018-09-09
```

If action is all and only Update-A, then the name will be assigned to Category 1.

If action contains multiple values where Update-A is the last action, then the name will be assigned to Category 2.

If action contains multiple values where Update-A is the action before Update, then the name will be assigned to Category 3.

To:

```
Name  Action    Date        Category
0001  Update    2017-01-02  
0001  Update-A  2017-02-09  2
0001  Update-A  2017-03-02
0001  Update-A  2017-01-05
0002  Update-A  2017-02-18  1
0002  Update-A  2017-03-17
0003  Update-A  2017-02-09  
0003  Update    2018-09-09  3

Sample:

Select Name, Max(Date), Category=
Case
   When Action='Update-A' (all) then '1'
   When Action='Update-A' (last) then '3'
   When Action='Update-A' (first) then '2'
Else 'N/A'
```

Comment: not sure what is needed based on the expected output shown.

Comment: Either 1, 2, 3 will be assigned once to the category column per name column if it meets certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions are your best bet:

```
Select Name, Max(Date), Category=
       (case when min(action) over (partition by name) = 'Update-A' and
                  max(action) over (partition by name) = 'Update-A'
             then '1'
             when max(date) over (partition by name) = 
                  max(case when action = 'Update-A' then date end)
             then '3'
             when max(case when action = 'Update-A' then date end) <
                  max(cate when action = 'Update' then date end)
             then '2'
             else 'N/A'
       end) as category
```

I'm not 100% sure that category 2 is exactly what you intend, but it works for the example in your data.